# dataGridView showing data wrong

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have 2 dataGridViews. The left one is populated with some data from a table named Fitness_Manager, and the right one with nothing at first,like in the picture:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5felP.png)

I want to click on a random row and to show me his children in the dataGridView from right (the 2 tables are in a 1:n relationship). But when I select the first row (for example) in dataGridView2, its children appear but also the column names from dataGridView1:

[the columns from the 2 dataGrids are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsS33.png)

Also, dataGridView1 deletes all the data, which I don't want:

[the children are shown but dataGridView1 is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srbqw.png)

How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data source=DESKTOP-EDEJRBT; Initial Catalog=FitnessManager; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();


    DataSet set = new DataSet();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Fitness_Manager",connection);
        set.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(set);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Sali(oras,capacitate,codFM) VALUES(@b,@c,@d)", connection);
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            string idS = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(idS);

            connection.Open();
            adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            connection.Close();

        }
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            // string idS = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
            //int id = Int32.Parse(idS);
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string idS = row.Cells["codf"].Value.ToString();
            int id = Int32.Parse(idS);

            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select cods,oras,capacitate from Sali Where codFM=" + id, connection);
            set.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(set);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = set.Tables[0];


        }
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're using one `DataSet` for both tables and clearing it between the button presses, perhaps this is why you're losing the data? Also I'd advice changing the name `set` as it is a contextual C# keyword, just as a good practice.

Comment: It worked. I used only one dataset and that was the problem!

Comment: I've done my best to make this comprehensible. Please don't use screenshots for code if at all possible.